# Can't use the value from the dropdown list to the databse in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SalesSystem
{
    public partial class Order : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MOE;Integrated Security=True";
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand("Select Itemid,ItemName from Item", conn);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = da.ExecuteReader();
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Itemname";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Itemid";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string orderdate = txtorderdate.Text;
            string customerid = txtcustomerid.Text;
            string itemid = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string qty = txtquantity.Text;



            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MOE;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand result = new SqlCommand("Insert Into [Order](Orderdate,Customerid,Itemid,OQty) Values ('" + orderdate + "','" + customerid + "','" + itemid + "','" + qty + "')", con);
            result.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this and click the "Add" button, the value of the dropdown list (itemid) is always inserted as the first value (001) not matter how many times I changed the dropdown list value.

Answer (score 1):

It is rebinding after every post back.  check this to make sure your drop down is bound only once during the first page load but not when you click Button

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
              SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
              conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MOE;Integrated Security=True";
              conn.Open();
              SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand("Select Itemid,ItemName from Item", conn);
              DropDownList1.DataSource = da.ExecuteReader();
              DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Itemname";
              DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Itemid";
              DropDownList1.DataBind();
              conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```